# How to debug iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

how can i debug applications for iPhone in Objective-C, XCode

i mean ok, XCode and debug mode is fine, but when my application crashes on 
BAD_ACCES (or smth. smilliar) i just get the trace to assembly

when iam debugging C++ and lets say want to access an invalid pointer, i get a trace right to the line of code where everything crashed... here i just get a trace to many internal functions in assembly, so i dont have a clue what and where went wrong

probably some release / retain problem, but how can i find out?

thank you

Comment: Have you tried doing a Build and Analyse? Although it isn't real time debugging, it should help you get to the route of leaks and over releasing.

Answer (score 4):

Here we go with the full answer:

I've had a look at your app and I think there is a problem with the combination of the UINavigationController and asynchronous http loading in two places. Enabling the zombies did reveal those two errer. The first on I was able to reproduce, the seconds one popped up several times and then not any more.

```
*** -[DetailViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x56d6030
*** -[SearchViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x56daa10
```

I've just throttled my bandwidth to see if those errors are connected to http requests. Look at [Throttling Bandwidth On A Mac][1] to set up a slow connection. I set it to 5KBytes/sec.

The first error occurs if you go very quickyl down to the details and then two levels up again and as a last action to trigger the error: click on search. The stacktrace shows a

```
#2    0x004545b8 in -[UIWebView webView:decidePolicyForMIMEType:request:frame:decisionListener:]
```

and there are some threads open, so looking at the dropdown, there is a webThread. Showing that thread reveals something going on with the webview loading the detailPages url. This hints that the webiew actually finished loading in a seperate thread and wasn't able to connect back to the webview itself `[DetailViewController respondsToSelector:]`. This can be easily proofed: remove the loading of the request for the webview: I wasn't able to reproduce the error.

**Solution problem 1**
The problem is easily fixed, as the webview is not released in the dealloc. Setting delegates to nil of objects is also recommended, but not needed in this case.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    webView.delegate = nil;
    [webView release];
}
```

**The second error**

The stackTrace shows a

```
 CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:
```

**Solution error**

Same as error 1, set the delegate to nil and release the locationManager.

---

When your app crashes you cann open up the debugger in the left hand window you can see the stacktrace. You can double click any line which will jump to correct position in your code(if the called method is of yours).

Goto Project->Edit Active Executable->Arguments Tab
Add the Variable in the lower window by clicking on +

```
Name:NSZombieEnabled 
Value:YES
```

This tries to resolve memory addresses to class names for bad excess errors.

To find out about memory leaks, open Run->Run with performance tool->Leaks. This will open up instruments which is a brillant tool to find leaks.

Comment: yes, but in the stacktrace i get a bunch of internal calls, and none of my own

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the stacktrace? There might be a clue, and yes not every line can jump to your code as it's Apple's code and that is not open.

Comment: This is interesting, can you put provide some code what and when this error occurs?

Comment: will send you the source, with description over email (its quite small), if you will provide your email address to me

Comment: Send over to nw at yanac dot de

Answer (score 1):

Are you using XCode 3? If so, I would highly advise upgrading to XCode 4. The debugger in XCode 4 is brilliant in comparison. It let's you step back through the code and see exactly what caused the crash.